# How do 'and' and 'or' act with non-boolean values in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

```
22 and 333/12 or 1
```

I have encountered the above line of code. The result is 27, but I could not quite understand what does `and` and `or` mean in this case. Can somebody explain to me, preferred with examples. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note this trick doesn't work if you want it to result in a value that is False when the condition is True -- `22 and None or 1` would give `1` not `None`. `(None, 1)[22]` does work, so long as it is OK for both the True and False values to be evaluated, as it doesn't short circuit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the ["and-or trick"](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html) -- `and` and `or` don't actually return boolean values; instead, they return one of their input arguments. People used to use this for control-flow.

As of python 2.5, it's not necessary anymore, because conditional expressions were introduced.

```
22 and 333/12 or 1
```

is equivalent to

```
333/12 if 22 else 1
```

Comment: The "`if else`" is far more readable. I'd hope people aren't still resorting to the and/or trick.

Comment: I think the inline `if ... else ...` wasn't implemented in older Python versions, so scripts that support them might still use it.

Comment: @Anorov It's more than readability, see my comment on the question.

Comment: "and-or trick" link is broken.  `cond and x or y ` is not a logical equivalent for `x if cond else y`.  A correct equivalent is `(cond and [x] or [y])[0]`.

Answer (score 6):

`A and B` returns A if A is false, or B otherwise:

```
>>> 0 and 1
0
>>> False and True
False
>>> True and 'yes'
'yes'
>>> True and ''
''
```

Similarly, 'A or B' returns A if A is true, or B otherwise:

```
>>> 0 or 1
1
>>> False or True
True
>>> '' or 'yes'
'yes'
>>> False or ''
''
>>> 'yes' or ''
'yes'
```

Comment: And since `and` has a higher precedence in Python than `or`, `22 and 333/27` gets evaluated rather than `333/12 or `.   `0 and 333/27 or 1` would return `1`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, nonzero numbers are counted as true for the purposes of boolean expressions, and zero is counted as false.  So even though both `and` and `or` are normally used with the booleans `True` and `False`, they can be used with numbers too.

The issue is: what is the value of an expression like `10 and 3`, where both of the values evaluate to true?  In C, which has similar integer-as-boolean semantics, the value of `10 && 3` is 1, the most commonly used true value.  However, in Python the value of this expression is 3, the second half of the and expression.  This makes sense because and short-circuits, meaning that `0 and 3` is 0, so `and` has "take the first value if it's false, the second otherwise" semantics.

What about the expression you posted?  By operator precedence, it's the same as

```
(22 and 333/12) or 1
```

The value of `22 and 333/12` is `333/12`, which is 27.  Since the or operator short-circuits, the Python interpreter takes the first true value when evaluating `27 or 1`, and gets 27.

Answer (score 0):

Let's separate this out:

```
22 and 333/12 or 1
(22 and 333/12) or (1) # Parentheses are nice
(22 and 27) or (1)     # 333/12 = 27 because you are using integers for division
22 and 27              # 22 and 27 is True, as neither of them is False
27                     # Not sure why anything is returned, but the second
                       # value always returned if it is True
```

Answer (score 0):

The logical operands and,or will come after division operator in this particular scenario as per the rules of precedence.

First it will calculate 333/12 which is 27 and then it will become 22 and 27 or 1 which is equivalent to 27 as and,or have equal precedences.

```
22 and 333/12 or 1
22 and 27 or 1
(22 and 27) or 1  OR 22 and (27 or 1)

27 ,27
```

But in case of Python 3.2 it's computing to 27.75.

```
>>> 22 and 333/12 or 1
27.75
>>> (22 and 333/12) or 1
27.75
>>> 22 and (333/12 or 1)
27.75
```

Comment: The `and` is evaluated before the `or`, see the other answers.