# Why does "return s and s.strip()" work when using filter?

Tags: python, list, filter, short-circuiting

```
def not_empty(s):
    return s and s.strip()

list(filter(not_empty, ['A', '', 'B', None, 'C', '  ']))
# result: ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I don't know why this worked.
I know that : x and y if x is false, then x, else y.
So first is return 'A' and 'A'.strip().
But this showed in python IDLE

> ```
> >>>'A' is True
> False
> >>>'A' is False
> False
> ```

So. not_empty('A') returned 'A', right? 'A'is not True, why is it in the result?

And why

> not_empty(' ')
>   ''

' ' is also False.

> ```
> >>>' ' is True
> False
> >>>' ' is False
> False
> ```

Comment: `'A' is True` and `bool('A') == True` is not the same thing.

Comment: Because `' '.strip()` is false

Comment: Is there a reason why a simple `[x.strip() for x in old if x is not None and x.strip() != '']` is not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translate your `filter` function into a good ol' `for` loop:

```
old = ['A', '', 'B', None, 'C', '  ']
new = []

for i in old:
    if i and i.strip():
        new.append(i)

print(new)
```

Outputs:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Why this happens is because of the `if` which evaluates the *truthiness* of expressions.

You should know that all *empty* iterables (including the empty string `''`), `0`, `False`, and `0.0` are all evaluated to `False` in an expression. There are some space strings, which when stripped, are reduced to the empty string which are also evaluated to `False`.

Going over each element, this is how your program runs:

```
Initial
old = ['A', '', 'B', None, 'C', '  ']
new = []

Iteration 1
i = 'A'
'A' and 'A'.strip() is evaluated to True
new = ['A']

Iteration 2
i = ''
'' is evaluated to False (short circuit)
new = ['A']

Iteration 3 (same as 1)
i = 'B'
...
new = ['A', 'B']

Iteration 4
i = None
None is evaluated to False
new = ['A', 'B']

Iteration 5 (same as 1, 3)
i = 'C'
...
new = ['A', 'B', 'C']

Iteration 6
i = '  '
' ' is True but ' '.strip() is False
new = ['A', 'B', 'C']

Final
new = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's do some basic debugging.

`"A" and "A".strip()` prints "A" to the shell

Now why does it do that. Well let's look up how `and` works

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797522/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values-in-python_)

"`A and B` returns `A` if `A is False`, and `B` otherwise"

So since `"A"` is not `0` or `False`, `not_empty` will return `"A".strip()`.
now
`"A".strip()=="A"`,
So the `not_empty` returns `"A"`

Similarly, when `filter` is called, it will apply the function and check the result, and it will not get `False` unless the stripped list is emptry. because of this, it will give you ['A', 'B', 'C'].