# Why is number || boolean a number?

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir but I couldn't find an answer to my question.
Here are some examples I have entered to `iex`.

```
expression   result
9 || true    9
true || 9    true
9 && true    true
true && 9    9
```

So, when there is an `||` it will evaluate to first argument, and `&&` to last when one argument is not boolean.
How are `||` and `&&` implemented? Why are they returning those results?

Comment: This is true in *most* languages that implement short-circuiting boolean logic without forcing the results to a narrowly-constrained boolean type. If the first side of the branch is true, you just return it exactly as it is, otherwise you return the other side; that way you preserve not only the truthiness logic as-desired, but also the exact values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result is a JavaScript equivalent to the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797522/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values-in-python is a Python equivalent to the question.

Comment: The key point is that when `X` is truthy, `X || Y = X` rather than `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common language facility in the context of short-circuiting boolean logic. To throw out pseudocode of some example cases where it's useful:

```
need_a_number() && calculate_number() # do the expensive calculate_number() call, and evaluate to
                                      # its result, only if need_a_number() is truthy.

get_a_string() || "default string"  # returns "default_string" if get_a_string() is falsey
```

If your `&&` and `||` returned only boolean values, you wouldn't be able to both branch and calculate in a single operation.

Answer (score 3):

While answer by Charles is correct it do not tell whole story. In general Elixir have 2 different sets of operators for working on "booleanish" values:

- `&&` and `||` - these works on all types, and [literally](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.2/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3182) are shortcuts for:

  ```
  case left do # equivalent to left && right
    x when x in [nil, false] -> x
    _ -> right
  end
  ```
- `and` and `or` which works only on `true` and `false` atoms and will fail with `BadBooleanError` when provided anything else.

And as it was said both of these operators are short-circuiting, which mean that these will cut computation as soon as the result is obvious.

Comment: The code example is great, but the comment is confusing, and I have no idea what it means --(Oh!  Now I do).  How about putting the comment above the code and shortening it to merely `left && right`.

Answer (score -2):

Programming languages implement the concept of truthy and falsy value types in order to use them in **boolean logic**. Some values are considered to be *false* and others are considered to be *true* when used in boolean operations and the fact that the last value of the function -- *or expression* -- is returned, allows us to short-circuit and branch our functions as mentioned in the previous answer.

This is true for every language I know.

In Elixir (1.7.3 compiled with Erlang/OTP 21) I think we have a consistent behaviour, even with number Zero:

```elixir
(0 || false) == 0 # true
(0 || false) === 0 # true
```

And just to compare, in Javascript (Google Chrome v74):

```js
(0 || false) == 0 // true
(0 || false) === 0 // false
```